# uniform keyword in HLSL

Tags: directx, hlsl

it seems that in HLSL i can but dont have to provide the uniform keyword for variables which come from the application. right?

why is that so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In HLSL global variables are considered uniform by default.

It's also settled that a variable coming out of the vertex shader stage for example is *varying* (HLSL doesn't need this keyword at all!).

Note that GLSL keywords uniform/varying are inherited from RSL 
(RenderMan shading language).